Migrating One-Time Purchase App to Google Play Billing Subscription (User Management)
I'm working on migrating my app from a one-time purchase model to a subscription model using Google Play Billing. I'm looking for best practices on how to manage users who have already purchased the one-time option during this transition.
My main questions are:
What are the recommended approaches to ensure a smooth transition for existing users who paid the one-time purchase?
How can I offer a fair value proposition for the new subscription model while considering existing users?
Are there any specific Google Play Billing API functionalities that might be helpful in this scenario (e.g., migrating purchase history or offering grandfathering options)?
I've extensively searched online documentation for Google Play Billing and best practices for migrating to subscriptions, but haven't found a definitive solution for managing existing one-time purchase users.
